# ObjectListView Column Reordering

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I've got a `dataTreeListView` which has got afew column headers as added to it as follows:

```
oCol2.IsVisible = false;
dataTreeListView.AllColumns.AddRange(new OLVColumn[] { oCol1, oCol2, oCol3, oCol4, oCol5});

dataTreeListView.KeyAspectName = id;
dataTreeListView.ParentKeyAspectName = ParentId;
dataTreeListView.DataSource = list;
dataTreeListView.RootKeyValue = 0;
```

The list itself has got 7 properties (inclusive of `Id` and `ParentId`).

What I'm trying to achieve is that, upon `selectedIndex` change of a combo box, the column header will change position.

```
From View (type1) (oCol2.IsVisible = false):
oCol1 (expandable) | oCol2 (hidden) | oCol3 |   oCol4 | oCol5

To View (type2) (oCol2.IsVisible = true):
oCol2 | oCol1 (expandable) | oCol3 | oCol4 | oCol5
```

What I got now is view (type1) is working correctly, but after switching to view type2, the expandable column is still at oCol1 instead of oCol2. It seems that I could not `switch` the primary column.

Any help for this?

Comment: the type2 view defines oCol2 first and then oCol1 (expandable). As per your question this looks like an expected output. Unless I am missing anything.

Comment: Hi theghostofc, I've tried to do something like this.

    dataTreeListView.AllColumns.Clear();
    oCol2.IsVisible = true;
    dataTreeListView.AllColumns.AddRange (new OLVColumn[] { oCol2, oCol1, oCol3, oCol4, oCol5, });

the result is still the same, the oCol1 at the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the ordering, change the `DisplayIndex` property on each column.

If you want to hide/show columns (as well as reordering them), you change the contents of `AllColumns` and then call `RebuildColumns()`. See [this FAQ](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/faq.html#how-do-i-hide-a-column)

If you want to swap between various column layouts, you can use `SaveState()` and `RestoreState()` See [this recipe](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html?highlight=savestate#how-can-i-save-and-restore-the-state-of-the-objectlistview)

Comment: Hi Grammarian, I've since used another approach to deal with the displaying of my data, thanks!